# Facebook developer running app now redirects to blank page

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

On my site there is a option to login with Facebook, for which we have integrated Facebook developer app with generated client id and secret Id. Earlier it was working fine but from last 3-4 it has stopped working.

Now when I click on "Login with FB" button. It shows FB login page to fill credentials. Once I fill my id and password, it takes too much time to redirect and redirects to blank page.

```
String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" + client_id + "&redirect_uri=" + request.getScheme() + "://"
            + (String) Utils.getValueFromVS(ActionConstants.APP_URL, InsightValueStack.SESSION) + "/user/fbLogin.do&client_secret="
            + secret_id + "&code=" + code;

        URL url1 = new URL(url);
        connection = url1.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            resp_Access_token.append(line);
        }
        reader.close();
```

I have no idea why it is behaving like this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Developer App not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658295/facebook-developer-app-not-working)

Comment: Pls dont ask the same ques again, instead elaborate your question. Else how could you expect someone to help you

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer the question. Is it correctly redirecting to your site and failing to load the page, or is it redirecting to the wrong page entirely?

Comment: A side note; last question you asked you tagged urgent, disappeared and didn't answer comments posted on the question for 18 hours. People add comments to get help answering your question since your question does not contain enough info. Reposting the same question instead of answering questions people ask in the comments to your question is not helpful from your side.

Comment: url created by application   https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=189879147805781&redirect_uri=http://182.73.181.60:8080/knimbus/user/fbLogin.do&client_secret=d75e3b1308754a2a00f693f56499fac4&code=AQAqWyeyAK61lkv8z3dx7amGek-u0F1d7hijA-SJ9lmDOM0KvDumWgfiGCsqhEN-1WCpSnTkp2auQFxCUxHOcrV3LC7Zrr_mp9isDlRpgAvsBQjrwVxeLzR_CtbwSh9x6uiN28F7sWW4dXF8R6D8ppPhDHIRZ2Ej3DWzD-gy0RC-L0fQAGyfvI_97B0fqMPlbupIbRv-53iML51Woe7Gu4T9YZF3EupxwxMCLGtgyzPW8Yzf4ZIM2Px9YNNnP8l-tv16yDQjBUvoawoyym69qBbswMrFSlYMq8yZg-ELuk45sUU9R_x8A1YuZ09vKlcU2uA              and it does not response